# How to make some of the listfield's rows focusable and others non-focusable?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I want to create a listfield in which some of the rows are non-focusable i.e when we scroll some of the rows should not get focus.
i have searched internet regarding the same but didn't get any help..
plz help...

all suggestions will be appreciated...

Comment: Vipin when we scroll the list filed then every time paint method as well as onFocus method of each row gets called.U can apply your custom logic there in the onfocus method.inside this method u can override the default focus color from blue to none as well as do whatever u want.this is just the logic that u need to implement...Hope it helps u

Comment: http://intridea.com/2011/2/25/blackberry-tip-change-the-default-focus-highlight-color-of-listfield?blog=company------------------this link will help u cahnge the default focus color to white or better to set the focus color equivalent to the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Vipin

A logic:

when we scroll the list filed then every time paint method as well as onFocus method of each row gets called.U can apply your custom logic there in the onfocus method.inside this method u can override the default focus color from blue to none as well as do whatever u want.this is just the logic that u need to implement...Hope it helps u

http://intridea.com/2011/2/25/blackberry-tip-change-the-default-focus-highlight-color-of-listfield?blog=company

http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-listfield-change.html

these links will help u change the default focus color to white or better to set the focus color equivalent to the background color.

Comment: Thanks Swati, that was quite helpful..  but in my project i have created a custom ListField. So i am wondering where to put the draw focus code (in custom listfield's class or in the class where i am using this listfield). i put the code in cutom listfield's class but that hides the focused row's content. plz suggest smthing....